# How solve error reading annotations in play framework 2

Tags: playframework-2.0

this is my proyect link
https://github.com/jstar88/LibreTitan

i got this exceptions compiling in localhost: play framework 2.1

> Unexpected exception

RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.User
No source available, here is the exception stack trace:

->java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.User

```
 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:54)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1034)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:565)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:252)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:124)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:210)

 com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultServerFactory.createServer(DefaultServerFactory.java:64)

 com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:59)

 play.db.ebean.EbeanPlugin.onStart(EbeanPlugin.java:79)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:63)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:63)

 scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:309)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:63)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:63)

 play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:63)

 play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)

 play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:62)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:133)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106)

 scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:106)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:104)

 scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)

 play.core.ReloadableApplication.get(ApplicationProvider.scala:104)

 play.core.server.Server$class.sendHandler$1(Server.scala:56)

 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:88)

 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$4.apply(Server.scala:87)

 scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:523)

 play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:87)

 play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:34)

 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:103)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:565)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:793)

 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:104)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:565)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:793)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)

 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:455)

 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:538)

 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:75)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:565)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:560)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:84)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:472)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:333)

 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)

 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:102)

 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)

 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

 java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: solved, from source http://ebeanorm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ebeanorm/ebean/trunk/src/main/java/com/avaje/ebeaninternal/server/deploy/parse/AnnotationAssocOnes.java?revision=1517&view=markup you can see that i was missing the corrispective @Entity

Comment: If you solved your own problem, place your answer in the answer box below instead of as a comment.

Comment: I am face the same exception, even though I have used annotation @Entity. Can you confirm the solution to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I got this problem when I used a `@MappedSuperclass` Class in a `List<?>` field.
Changing it to `@Entity` made the exception disappear.

Answer (score -1):

Add @Entity at the top of the class

Comment: Good answers include some explanation, and not just a copy of the answer already provided in the comments.