# Play Framework Error with Ebean Models - Error reading annotations and Error with association

Tags: playframework, ebean

I am building an Ebean server in my application.  Here is the code:

```
public Result refreshDataFromProduction() {
        if (hasCorrectAccess(RoleType.BAMANAGER) != true && hasCorrectAccess(RoleType.SEMANAGER) != true
                && hasCorrectAccess(RoleType.ADMIN) != true) {
            return ACCESS_DENIED;
        } else {
            // Get the eEbean server...
            // Get the application.conf...
            String serverEnvironment = "test";
            String getValue = "";
            Configuration appConfig = Configuration.root();

            DataSourceConfig dataconfig = new DataSourceConfig();
            getValue = Messages.get("db." + serverEnvironment + ".url");
            dataconfig.setUrl(getValue);
            getValue = Messages.get("db." + serverEnvironment + ".driver");
            dataconfig.setDriver(getValue);
            getValue = Messages.get("db." + serverEnvironment + ".username");
            dataconfig.setUsername(getValue);
            getValue = Messages.get("db." + serverEnvironment + ".password");
            dataconfig.setPassword(getValue);

            // Create the server config...
            ServerConfig c = new ServerConfig();
            c.setName(serverEnvironment);       
            c.setDdlGenerate(false);
            c.setDdlRun(false);
            c.setDefaultServer(true);
            c.setRegister(true);
            c.setDataSourceConfig(dataconfig);
            // Add all Models here...
            c.addClass(User.class);

            EbeanServer server = EbeanServerFactory.create(c);
            server.save(server);

            return ok(genericsuccess.render());
        }
    }
```

The error occurs at this line:

```
EbeanServer server = EbeanServerFactory.create(c);
```

Here is the full error:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.User]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.play$core$j$JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$super$onError(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:35)
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$anonfun$onError$2.apply(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:35)
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter$$anonfun$onError$2.apply(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:35)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onError(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:35)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error reading annotations for models.User
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:85)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1076)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:580)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:301)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:130)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:122)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:42)
        at com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.createInternal(EbeanServerFactory.java:108)
        at com.avaje.ebean.EbeanServerFactory.create(EbeanServerFactory.java:67)
        at jobs.Jobs.refreshDataFromProduction(Jobs.java:1533)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error with association to [class models.LinkedAccount] from [models.User.linkedAccounts]. Is class models.LinkedAccount registered?
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocManys.readToOne(AnnotationAssocManys.java:307)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocManys.read(AnnotationAssocManys.java:57)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.AnnotationAssocManys.parse(AnnotationAssocManys.java:48)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.ReadAnnotations.readAssociations(ReadAnnotations.java:76)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readDeployAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:1076)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.readEntityDeploymentAssociations(BeanDescriptorManager.java:580)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.BeanDescriptorManager.deploy(BeanDescriptorManager.java:301)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.InternalConfiguration.<init>(InternalConfiguration.java:130)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:122)
        at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.DefaultContainer.createServer(DefaultContainer.java:42)
```

I found a few posts, but those don't seem to help me:

[Error reading annotations play framework 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22397924/error-reading-annotations-play-framework-2-2)

[How solve error reading annotations in play framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782362/how-solve-error-reading-annotations-in-play-framework-2)

Here are the classes I am working with:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Column(unique = true)
    public String fullname;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<LinkedAccount> linkedAccounts;

...
}

@Entity
public class LinkedAccount extends AppModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public User user;

    public String providerUserId;
    public String providerKey;
    public Long userId;
    public String email;

...
}
```

I am guessing it has to do with `@OneToMany` and the `@ManyToOne` references, but not sure how to correct.